# Desktop shortcut in ubuntu not working (not reading a text file in the source folder)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, shortcut, pyqt6

I am new to Ubuntu. I compiled a Python script to an executable file in Ubuntu 22.04 using PyInstaller (one file). It connects to a database by reading login credentials from a text file in the same directory.
such as IP address, password, port and username. The code is:

```py
def remote_db_connector():
  txtPath = Path.cwd().joinpath("text.txt")
  myfile = open(txtPath)
  x = myfile.read()
  myfile.close()
  return x
```

I collect the individual components by using `split()`. It works perfectly from the folder where the executable and `text.txt` file resides. When I create a desktop shortcut in Ubuntu 22.04 it does not read the text file and the program does not run. The desktop shortcut script is as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Mypro
Exce=/home/softwares/Mypro
Icon=/home/softwares/Myico.png
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=false
```

(I found it out by giving the shortcut script `Terminal=true`). Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spell `Exec` correctly, maybe add a `Path` to your desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Mypro
Exec=/home/softwares/Mypro
Path=/home/softwares
Icon=/home/softwares/Myico.png
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=false
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't share <s>your .desktop file nor</s> the entire script, but from what I can see, it looks like you're giving your script wrong directions by using Path.cwd

Try it yourself.

Go into /path/to/yourscript.py and run your script as you normally do.

Then switch to the parent directory and try the same. It will fail.

pathlib.Path.cwd returns the directory from where the script *was invoked*, not its location.

exchange

```
txtPath = Path.cwd().joinpath("text.txt")
```

with

```
txtPath = Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("text.txt")
```